# Вывести количество часов с правильным окончанием час(а/ов)

Tags: python, python-2.x

Сделал так :

```
import datetime

def showHours( hours ):
    result = "{0} {1}."
    lastdigits = hours % 20
    s = ""

    if lastdigits == 1:
        s += "час"
    elif lastdigits > 1 and lastdigits < 5:
        s += "часа"
    else:
        s += "часов"

    return result.format( hours, s )

print showHours(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
```

Какие ещё варианты возможны?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот принимали бы вы участие в переводе интерфейса Хэшкода, и не пришлось бы задавать этот вопрос :-)

Правильный вариант такой:

```py
def pluralRusVariant(x):
    lastTwoDigits = x % 100
    tens = lastTwoDigits // 10
    if tens == 1:
        return 2
    ones = lastTwoDigits % 10
    if ones == 1:
        return 0
    if ones >= 2 and ones <= 4:
        return 1
    return 2

def showHours(hours) :
    suffix = ["час", "часа", "часов"][pluralRusVariant(hours)]
    return "{0} {1}".format(hours, suffix)
```

Ваш вариант выдаст неправильный ответ при `hours == 32`.
Получится `32 часов`, а надо `32 часа`.

Comment: Извините, может чего-то недопонимаю. Но в чем именно мог бы помочь опыт перевода? ;)

Comment: Что-то я не досчитался у себя). Понравилось ваше решение. Спасибо.

Comment: @sys_dev: Ну, при переводе такие случаи попадались сплошь и рядом, и у нас была дискуссия о том, как правильно оформлять формы множественного числа. Впрочем, кое-где всё ещё неправильно, как вы можете видеть :)

Comment: @strol: Пожалуйста!

Comment: Для справки: вот таблица применения форм множественного числа (то есть, функции типа `pluralRusVariant`) по _всем_ языкам: http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/25/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html

Comment: @Jack_oS, @insolor: спасибо!`

Answer (score 0):

Все там правильно работает, но есть опечатки. В

```
tens = latTwoDigits / 10
```

должно быть

```
tens = latTwoDigits // 10
```

Ну и буква пропущена в имени переменной. Спасибо за скрипт, очень удобно.

Comment: это, скорее, комментарий к ответу... а так да: &&, latTwoDigits, нет двоеточий у if... но есть пометка "псевдокод", так что все по-чесному

Comment: Я, к сожалению, совсем не знаю Python, так что смело правьте мой ответ